# Reloading of failed tiles in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, tiles

In OpenLayers 5, if loading of some tiles has failed (because of temporary network issue, for example), those tile are never attempted to load again.

Is it possible to force OL to retry loading of those tiles?

Workflow:

- disable network
- zoom in (to zoomlevel 2), all tiles fail
- zoom in again
- enable network
- zoom out, you are back in zoomlevel 2 now. No tiles are displayed <- OL should reload those errorneous tiles

Goal is not to reload whole layer - OpenLayers should attempt to reload only failed tiles every time, when those are displayed on map.

Comment: @TomazicM No, there's completely different story in mentioned post.

Comment: You could force retries for individual tiles `source.on('tileloaderror', function(event) { event.tile.load(); });` but beware of infinite loops if you request tiles which will never be available.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, that's good idea, but it doesn't work for my scenario. 'tileloaderror' is fired immediately after failure, and there's no point to retry so soon. And if user zoom around and visits that problematic map area later - tiles aren't attempted to load and also 'tileloaderror' is not shot again.

Comment: What I had in mind is method `source.tileCache.expireCache`, but now I see it's even not documented. You could do a litle research about it in `ol` source code and combine it with `tileloaderror` event that Mike proposed.

Comment: Thanks, idea to somehow remove specific tiles from cache, based on tileloaderror, seems promising. I'll check that out.

Comment: So I got some results with hackish solution: 1) On tileloaderror event, collect failed tile keys to array. 2) On map zoom level change, remove those tiles from tileCache - so if user returns to previous zoom, failed tiles will be loaded again. It didn't make sense to remove tiles from tileCache immediately - that way, reloads would happen on map pan. Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Great! It would be nice to decribe (with details) your solution in answer so others may profit fom it. If it's hidden in comments, nobody will find it.